# Set operations on $A$ and $B$

Tags: elementary-set-theory

I am a bit confused right now, in one of the practice questions for my book it says 
$$A,B \subset X$$

$$B = A \cup ((X \setminus  A) \cap B)$$

However, when I simplify it, I get that it equals

$$A \cup B$$

How does it equal $B$?

Comment: Indeed, that would mean $A\subset B$. Can be a mistake, or a assumption they make.

Comment: How does A being a subset of B make this statement true?

Comment: If $A \subset B$, then $B = A \cup B$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$B =  \{ x \in B \} = \{ x \in B \cap (A \cup (X$ \ $A))\}$ = $\{ x \in (B \cap A) \cup (B \cap X$ \ $A))\}$

So for those to be equal $A \subset B$ is needed and your book is **wrong**

An example:
$A= [0,2]$, $B=[1,3]$, $X=[0,5]$.
If you take $[0,2] \cup ( (2,5] \cap [1,3]$) you get $[0,3]$, and that's not $B$